# Portable interpretation of IOSTAT error codes in Fortran's OPEN statement?

Tags: fortran

The fortran `OPEN` statement places a system-dependent error code in the integer given as its optional `IOSTAT` specifier. For Intel Fortran, I've found the documentation of the error codes on [software.intel.com](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-list-of-run-time-error-messages). Starting from this, I could write an function/subroutine that converts iostat-values to human-readable values. Intel also provides a file `for_iosdef.for` that defines symbolic names for the values.

In principle, I could repeat the same for all supported compilers, but is there some *portable* way of interpreting the codes, or at least a subset thereof? Plus, for gfortran, there doesn't seem to be an official list, only unofficial lists like on [hep.manchester.ac.uk](http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/samt/misc/gfortran_errors.html).

Comment: At least for gfortran, error codes are a little more complicated than suggested by the above URL.  Error codes between 1 and 5000 are from the operating system's errno.h.  It's been a long time, so details are hazy.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/fortran/2006-October/014954.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep it portable, adhere to what the standard says: [Fortran 2008 Final Draft](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007r1.pdf) page 242 Section 9.11.5 "IOSTAT= specifier":

In short IOSTAT is "processor-dependent".
However there are a few defined values, which are specified in ISO_FORTRAN_ENV:

- IOSTAT_EOR (End of record)... negative integer
- IOSTAT_END (End of File)... negative integer
- IOSTAT_INQUIRE_INTERNAL_UNIT (Inquired an internal file)... positive integer
- 0 no error nor EOF nor EOR occured

All other errors are positive integers different from IOSTAT_INQUIRE_INTERNAL_UNIT. Their value however is not specified.

A few propertiese can be Inquired with the INQUIRE statement, e.g.: if you are allowed to read or write to the file.

Comment: This is the approach I usually take - you can know whether you've reached the EOF or EOR, whether you have a different error, or whether it's a successful read.

Comment: @Tine198 So essentially, there is no way to detect in a portable manner important error cases like "file did not exist", at least not from `IOSTAT`?

Comment: @kdb No there is no other way to get it from IOSTAT. If two error codes are the same, it is most likely just pure coincidence. Take the [IBM Error codes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.aix.doc/language_ref/languageerrors.html?view=kc) you can compare them with the one from Intel... 
58 means nearly the same ( Error in Format specifier) but for the [PGI compiler](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/19.5/x86/pgi-ref-guide/index.htm#msg-fort-runtm-errs) the closest I could find was 221. You can check with INQUIRE if a file exists or not.

Comment: @Tine198 Of course it is possible to make such a check, but compared to being able to directly interpret IOSTAT, it would be more brittle. I guess this leaves as the only possibility to handle possible error conditions (like file not found) before `OPEN()`, and just forward the IOMSG to the log for unexpected conditions, if letting the program crash isn't acceptable. It helps a lot though, to *know* that the standard doesn't standardize more error codes / where it does when lookup is needed.

Answer (score 3):

As of Fortran 2003, the `IOMSG` specifier is available, which allows obtaining human-readable error messages.

Sadly, there is no reliable way to obtain the full error message, as it takes a single `CHARACTER(LEN=...)` argument, and fills it with as many characters, as the variable can hold, which may include the full path of the file. In my real-world usecase, I had to use at least a `CHARACTER(LEN=256)` variable.

It also does not allow reacting to specific error conditions at runtime reliably.

Comment: The `IOMSG` specifier is useful for qualitative output, but if you're trying to portably control flow (eg., am I at the end yet?), `IOSTAT` is the way to go. Seems to me like OP is asking about flow control and `IOSTAT` values.

Comment: @Ross I am the OP ;) Since I've found a partial answer while writing the question, I posted as Q&A format.