How to safely check whether a Fortran file exists when reading it with Python?
I need to read in Python a file written in Fortran. To do this, I'm using numpy's f2py. Basically, I write a parse.f90 file:
      subroutine read_params(filename, params)
      implicit none
      ! Argument Declarations !
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
      integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
      ! Variable Declarations
      integer :: i

      open (unit=1,status="unknown",file=filename,form="unformatted")
      rewind 1
      read(1) (params(i), i=1, 4)

      end subroutine read_params

Then I compile it with
python -m numpy.f2py -c -m parse parse.f90

And now I can import it in my Python script:
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from .parse import read_params

def do_stuff_with_params(path: Path): 
    params = read_params(path)
    # do something with the parameters
    return

Now, my issue is that sometimes the Fortran file may not exist, for example because the user of do_stuff_with_params passed it the wrong path. Since however path is not a Python file object, the usual with open trick doesn't apply. So far, I used the following workaround:
def do_stuff_with_params(path: Path): 
    if not path.exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError(f'{path} does not exist ')
    params = read_params(path)
    # do something with the parameters
    return

But this isn't ideal for the usual reasons (the file may be moved or deleted between the if check and when it's actually opened). Also, I actually need to read the file twice because of Fortran limitations (long story...), so I would have to add two if statements. How can I solve this? I was wondering if I could raise an exception in parse.f90 and pass it to the Python interpreter, but I don't know how to do it.

You certainly cannot raise Python exceptions in Fortran (not in an easy way, you would have to call Python from Fortran), nor you can raise C++ or any other. The normal way not just in Fortran and especially when mixing languages used to be passing error codes. Many C functions return error codes as well.

@VladimirFГероямслава error codes are a bad idea, because the iostat values depend on the compiler (they're not prescribed by the standard) and this is absolutely a limitation of Fortran. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637739/portable-interpretation-of-iostat-error-codes-in-fortrans-open-statement

You can, of course, translate the values as you wish. Anything bigger than 1 to 1 and anything lower than -1 to -1, for example.  You can also test whether the file exists using inquire and use the logical values. There are many possibilities. The error code returned absolutely does not have to be the iostat value itself. Anyway, I do not see what else could you do otherwise. Error codes are the way to go when mixing languages in general. You can also pass the iomsg message for the details.

@VladimirFГероямслава what is inquire? The interpretation of the iomsg is likely even less portable than the interpretation of iostat. Anyway, comments are not for extended discussion. If you know how to do this, you can write an answer.

My "answer" is, pass an error code. Nothing more. It is up to you to set them to some values that are meaningful to you. Passing directly the numbers from iostat or any other system function from POSIX or from Windows file API is a bad idea. You should pass some codes you define end set in your procedure and it is up to you to do that. Inquire is a Fortran command that could be used. Various OS API functions could be used as well.

IMHO rewind 1 not necessary

Exceptions do not exist in Fortran so there is no Exception handling. But the external file handling statements can now take optional iostat and iomsg clauses.The iostat is an integer which returns a non-zero value if there is an error but the execution will not stop.You can add them to the open command in the Fortran code:
integer :: my_iostat
character (256) :: my_iomsg

open (unit=1,status="unknown",file=filename,form="unformatted",iostat=my_iostat, iomsg=my_iomsg)
if (my_iostat/=0) then
   ! put some values in params you could use in Python to identify that is an error
else
   ! read the file
end if

In the Python code you must check if the returned values ​​match the ones you defined for error otherwise the file was read without problems.

You can change the Fortran code a little more and add an intent(out) variable to return the error code given by iostat or an error code defined by you.
subroutine read_params(filename, params, error_code)
implicit none
! Argument Declarations !
character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
integer, intent(out) :: error_code
! Variable Declarations
integer :: i
integer :: my_iostat
character (256) :: my_iomsg

open (unit=1,status="unknown",file=filename,form="unformatted",iostat=my_iostat, iomsg=my_iomsg)
if (my_iostat/=0) then
   error_code = my_iostat   ! or you can define your own error code
   ! you can do something here
else
   error_code = 0   ! or a value you want
   ! read the file
end if
end subroutine read_params

Now in Python code you can check the error code returned and act accordingly.

Do not use this kind of formatting for the code. It looks bad and is also hard to correct. The buttons provided in the editor box will format code properly. You can also do it manually by placing three ``` ticks on the lines before and after the code block. Do not add any HTML entities.

You probably could raise Python exceptions from Fortran by calling some C to Python bindings but it would be quite complicated. Similarly in C++, even though C++ does have exceptions, you cannot directly raise a Python exception from C++ because those are C++ exceptions, not the Python ones. You wouůd have to use some C++ to Python bindings.

how do I understand what was the error, i.e., if the file doesn't exist, or if it exists but there is an error reading it? IOSTAT codes are not defined by the standard, so I cannot reliably interpret them

@DeltaIV You should see whether the iostat value was raised by the open command or by a read command. That should not be a problem at all. If you want to be able to distinguish, e.g., non-existent file and access denied that you have to inquire for existence first but normally it is enough to know that the open failed. But if you want to know more, there aere ways. You can also called the system.procedures provided by your OS (e.g., POSIX) for the details.

@Lewis your answer looks ok, but "putting some values in params" is not a robust approach my opinion. It's better to add a new intent(out) variable to the Fortran code which contains the error code, and pass it back to Python, which will handle it. If you make that modification, I'll accept your answer.

@DeltaIV this is a simple solution without changing the code too much, but anyone can change the code as they wish or think is best to return the error code. I added a solution with an intent(out) variable returning the error code.

@DeltaIV , Why iostat=<var>? IMHO, using open(..., err=<label1>) and read(...,, err=<label2>) will allow you to get shorter and more understandable code.

@Serge3leo if you read the question, he only wants to know if the Fortran code open a valid file and ensure the data returned to Python code is from a file. Fortran error codes here are not important  and with IOSTAT you just need to check if it's value is zero.

@Lewis , open(..., err=<label1>) is designed for compact and clear error handling, for example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79245899/8585880
